# How to get a required parameter from JSON String using robotframework keyword

Tags: json, robotframework

The following is my JSON response string

```
{
 "macKey": "This_is_a_Test_QED_MAC_Key_Which_Needs_to_be_at_Least_32_Bytes_Long",
"subject": "delivery@token.com",
"audience": "qed:test",
"expirationTime": "2016-03-09T23:07:52Z",
"notBeforeTime": "2016-03-09T23:07:52Z",
"jwtId": "",
"permissions": [
"MANAGE_SYSTEM"
],
"useCompactPermissions": false,
"url": "http://172.30.2.155:8080/",
"generatedToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0Iiwic3ViIjoiZGVsaXZlcnlAdG9rZW4uY29tIiwiYXVkIjoicWVkOnRlc3QiLCJxZWRwIjpbIm1hbmFnZVN5c3RlbSJdLCJleHAiOjE0NTc1NjQ4NzJ9.8KlDoK-t6HoOth3na2x6drEAFfXCGLKLt3aAMGg0r0U",
"qeda": null,
"qedp": [
"manageSystem"
],
"issueTime": "2016-03-09T09:34:40Z"
}
```

From the above one I need to take *generatedToken* value.

Answer (score 0):

### Using "To JSON" from RequestsLibrary

If you are using [RequestsLibrary](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/) to get the JSON data, you can use the [To JSON](http://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests/#To%20Json) keyword to convert it to an object. You can then use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to access the individual fields.

For example:

```
| | ${json}= | To JSON | ${response}
| | log to console | \n the token is ${json["generatedToken"]}
```

### Using "Evaluate" from the BuiltIn library

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to run the standard python function [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert a json string to an object. As long as the data doesn't have any triple-quoted strings, this will work:

```
| | ${json}= | Evaluate | json.loads('''${response}'''} | json
| | log to console | \n the token is ${json["generatedToken"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robotframework-httplibrary](https://github.com/peritus/robotframework-httplibrary)
then you can get it like this:

`${value}=    Get Json Value    ${json}    /generatedToken`

Answer (score -1):

```
${Ref_Id_Value}    Get Json Value    ${POSTResp.content}    /doInitiateFundsTransferResponseBody/transactionInformation/transactionReferenceNumber
```

You can use the `Get Json Value` method, I think.