# Robot framework get from JSON list

Tags: robotframework

I have data like this

```
{"_embedded":[
  {"attr_name":"attr_value_1"},
  {"attr_name":"attr_name_2"}
 ]
}
```

and I want to get the first attribute `attr_value_1`.

Do you know any nice way how to do it in Robot framework? Something like `Get JSON /_embedded[0]/attr_name` ?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35891061/7432.

Comment: I don't think so, he wan't just "generatedToken" which is not a variable in json array

Comment: Both this question and the one I marked as a duplicate are about getting an attribute out of some json data based on the key. How is yours different? If I were to answer this question, the answer would be almost exactly the same as that other question.

Comment: Also, is this actual data? it looks like illegal json, since the same key appears twice. If it's illegal json, the solution will be different than if it's valid json.

Comment: I think it is legal - list of objects with atr_name property. I also think that this question is duplicate. Problem is how to get property from object in a list inside an object in dictionary, though question should be about dictionaries.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think the discussion went wrong and leading not to solution :( . In the "duplicate" question I am able to answer, here not. Are you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the JSON data to a python object, and then use robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to get at the element. In python the value is referenced as `data["_embedded"][0]["attr_name"]`, which translates directly to robot extended variable syntax of `${data["_embedded"][0]["attr_name"]}`

Here is a complete example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${json}=    catenate    SEPARATOR=\n
    ...  {"_embedded":[
    ...    {"attr_name":"attr_value_1"},
    ...    {"attr_name":"attr_name_2"}
    ...   ]
    ...  }
    ${data}=  evaluate    json.loads('''${json}''')    json
    should be equal as strings    ${data["_embedded"][0]["attr_name"]}    attr_value_1
    should be equal as strings    ${data["_embedded"][1]["attr_name"]}    attr_name_2
```