# how to get the second element of json

Tags: json, robotframework

I have this JSON

```
[
  ["pimenta & guedes", "Rodrigo"],
  ["24", "29"],
  ["32", "10"],
  ["77", "5"],
  ["Cartao", ""]
]
```

How can I get the second element, `Rodrigo`?

I am using Robot Framework and I have tried this command :

```
${FILECONTENT}=    Get File    c:/aa/webdemo-master2/login_tests/sample.txt
#Log to console    ${FILECONTENT}
${JSON}=  evaluate  json.loads($FILECONTENT)  json
Log to console  ${JSON}
Log  Hello, my name is ${JSON[0]}
```

But the result is `(Hello, my name is ['pimenta & guedes', 'Rodrigo'])`

But I would like to get `(Hello, my name is Rodrigo)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json handling in ROBOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262216/json-handling-in-robot)

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37462112/5468463

Answer (score 5):

Your JSON is a two dimensional array. ${JSON[0][1]} should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: hy Nabin..  I tryed (Log  Hello, my name is  ${JSON[0][1]}) but it produce this error : FAIL Invalid log level 'Rodrigo'.