# How to extract data from API that is in html format using Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to extract data returned from API in html format from  the following tag. I need the value.

```
     <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
    value="CfDJ8HAHZQfAcMxBmpaspuVDRFPEKRneMMKaS7FGTmqmlPl- 
   xzvjkuePYhTesJqt0FABIwdSzEok25kZRCLzWX_8tdmtmCRJnrdYrP2PR-HZXcFzcGaSuQXbtL4qS6xfjlW_1qVAdMilo8Js9XzdEqlKsB3EKLKNqqubcsT98AkfbJTisZO_Q9vXg8crfafEouhBFQ" />
```

*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary
Library  XML

*** Variables ***
${login_url}    https://testworthy.us

*** Test Cases ***
get api
Create Session    mysession     ${login_url}
${response}=    Get Request    mysession    /Login
Log To Console  ${response.content}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Robot framework get from JSON list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462112/robot-framework-get-from-json-list)

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: You forgot quotes from `${user_key}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is: it doesn't know what `user1` is. `user1` comes from a variable, but you still need to use quotes when forming a valid reference to the data:

```
${username}=    Set Variable    ${user_data['users']['${user_key}']['username']}
${user_data['users']['user1']['username']}
#                                                    ^           ^
```