# How to fetch an attribute value from a variable, having the content of a JSON response

Tags: json, robotframework

I'm using the Robot Framework API automation. Here, storing the JSON response in a variable [POSTResp.content]. I.e., "POSTResp.content" has the whole response, as given below. Please help me to get an attribute's value (for ex, value of referenceId) from the stored content.

Example of JSON response:

```
{
"serviceResponseHeader": {
    "responseContext": {
        "responseCode": "MS19",
        "responseDescription": "Success",
        "serviceResponseTimeInGMT": "18 Sep 2018 16:12:43 GMT"
    },
    "requesterContext": {
        "applicationCode": null,
        "applicationSubCode": null,
        "countryCode": null,
        "requesterReferenceNumber": null,
        "requestTimeInGMT": "30 Jun 2015 11:54:49 GMT",
        "requesterUserIdentity": "23483",
        "requesterGroupIdentity": "1620",
        "requesterIpAddress": "",
        "sessionIdentity": "2536kjhfdashfkhfsab",
        "ssoSessionIdentity": "2536kjhfdashfkhfsab",
        "requesterAbbreviatedGroupName": "NEWCOMP"
    },
    "serviceContext": {
        "serviceVersionNumber": "1.0",
        "serviceCode": "30"
    }
},
"getProxyDetailResponseBody": {
    "proxyDetails": {
        "proxyType": "",
        "proxyValue": "20140005K",
        "referenceId": "PR18090000847597",
        "transactionId": "18091801657466"
    }
}
```

}

I've tried the below ways,

1) ${json}    To JSON    ${POSTResp.content}    true
log to console    \n the Proxy ID is ${json["proxyValue"]}

Result: Resolving variable '${json["proxyValue"]}' failed: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

2) ${json}    Evaluate    json.loads(${POSTResp.content}}    json
log to console    \n the Proxy ID is ${json["proxyValue"]}

Result: failed: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35891061/7432

Answer (score 1):

Issues with your two approaches:

1) the library keyword call passes a true argument (well, truth-like) to the pretty_print parameter:

```
 ${json}    To JSON    ${POSTResp.content}   true
```

Looking at the library's source, in that case the keyword does not return a dict object - but a string, a beatified version of the source json. That coincides with the error your received.
Remove the "true" argument and it must return a dict.

2) In the `Evaluate` surround the variable with triple quotes (python's literal string):

```
${json}    Evaluate    json.loads('''${POSTResp.content}'''}
```

json

Without it, the framework just dumped the variable's value, which raised a python syntax error.

By the way, try not to make your variables with language keywords/library names - like `${json}` up there.